# /usr/bin/node not found systemctl service

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, service, digitalocean

Создал дроплет в Digitalocean, Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вызове `node` все работает прекрасно, но при запуске сервиса, ничего не работает выбрасывая ошибку приведенную в теме.

Что может быть не так?

Comment: возможно, говорит что WorkingDirectory не существует. Чтобы другим людям с похожей проблемой легче было этот вопрос найти, в виде текста добавьте вывод ошибки.

Comment: WorkingDirectory есть, пути брал через pwd.

Comment: в тот момент когда сервис запускается уже подключён (mount) `/home` ?

Comment: Честно говоря, не могу дать ответ на этот вопрос. Сервис запускаю руками в уже работающей системе, насколько я полагаю, `/home` должен быть примонтирован.

Comment: Для проверки вместо node, /bin/true запустите. Полезно разрешения на папках, включая промежуточные посмотреть для соответствующего пользователя.

Comment: `Failed at step CHDIR spawning /bin/true: No such file or directory` результат отрицательный :(

Comment: очевидно, что проблема с директорией. Проверьте что она подключена на момент запуска сервиса, разрешения на неё (и промежуточные) для нужно пользователя есть.

Comment: Да, вы были абсолютно правы, что проблема с директорией. Получилось так, что путь до исполняемого файла был неправильным. Спасибо, за помощь.